# UIDevice does not work in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uidevice

I try to use following code to get my device information:

`UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion`

But I got an error as bellow shown:

`Use of unresolved identifier UIDevice`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

add the UIKit import

```
import UIKit
```

Comment: This gets me a "No Such Module "UIKit"